# How to determine in Windows whether file exists, does not exist or this can't be known (using c)

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I have to clean up from a list of files the ones that do not exist any more. The ones whose status is indeterminable should be given a warning about but left on the list. Sounds simple enough. However, the c functions I tried to solve this with don't seem to give a reliable answer between whether the file really does not exist or it e.g. resides on a network share that is at the moment inaccessible (e.g. due to network problems).

stat function sets errno to ENOENT if the file can't be reached, so that is indistinguishable from the file not actually existing.

FindFirstFile in some cases sets last error (obtainable with GetLastError()) to ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND when the network share can't be reached. 
Yes, I know FindFirstFile is for reading directories, but I thought I could deduce what I need to know by the error code it sets.

Also GetFileAttributes seems to in some cases set last error to ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND in case the network drive is unreachable.

Comment: Uh, so you expect something in Windows to be able to determine that a file really does not exist, when it looks like it is on a non-reachable network share? That sounds theoretically impossible to me, but perhaps I misunderstand the question.

Comment: No, I must have expressed myself badly. For a file I want to know:
* yes, it definitely exists. 
* no, it definitely does not exist. This has been checked from the file system, whether it is local or a network drive.
* the folder containing the file can't be reached or there's not enough permissions to access it so the existence of the file can't be determined.

Or is there something I missed - why would answering this question be theoretically impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateFile` does set LastError to 0x35 (network path not found) if network share is not availiable and to 0x2 (system cannot find the path specified) if share is availiable, but file does not exist

Comment: I have tested this for a while and it seems to work reliably. Thanks!

Comment: How would someone think that solved their problem, but not up-vote it??

Answer (score 1):

```
if((f = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL){
    //File does not exist or can not be read
}else{
    //File exists
    fclose(f);
}
```

Drawbacks:

You don't know if a file is nonexistent or just can't be read (privileges etc),

On the other hand, it is 100% portable.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately what you mention in the drawbacks is precisely the distinction I need to be able to make.